# Trying to Get Rid of White Space in SSRS Report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a Report where I need to Hide Duplicates but unfortunately I now have white space in the Returned Data where the Duplicate Records used to be.

How do I remedy this so my Report doesn't look so unprofessional?

I have searched the internet and found answers for hiding rows where there is no data, but in my report there is data that I don't want to show. I would just take it out of the Query but the way the Tables are set up that is not an option.

**EDIT**
I am working with a Tablix, there is no ConsumeContainerWhitespace property that I have been able to find.
this is not a case of an extra page being added at the end of the report on Export.
I have blank spaces in between records.

**EDIT**

```
=iif(Fields!CaseNbr.Value = Previous(Fields!CaseNbr.Value), True, False)
```

that is the code that I have written into the Hidden Property under Visibility in the Properties Section of The Row of Placeholders for my Data.
this leaves empty Cells in the table of information where the duplicate information is being hidden.

My Table looks like this:

```
Name            Title
Malione         Programmer

Manny           Watchman
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found here.

[http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/hidden-rows-still-displayed-9660.shtml](http://web.archive.org/web/20130530032649/http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/hidden-rows-still-displayed-9660.shtml)

You are likely entering your expression in the text visibility properties instead of the row group visibility.  Using the row group will remove the entire row, text and white space.

Comment: this makes Sense! unfortunately I don't have the report up to check this, but I am going to mark it as the answer because I believe that this would work!  thank you so much for taking the time to answer this old question.  this will definitely stick in my mind!

Comment: 404 not found. Your link has gone. Its better to put the relevant information into your answer than just linking to it.

Comment: @JamesKhoury the Link has been fixed, sort of

Answer (score 2):

This might help: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2011/03/18/the-case-of-the-extra-page/

First thing to try is the ConsumeContainerWhitespace property I mention at the end.

Comment: You're correct. It's not a tablix property. It's a report property as stated in the blog post. Click anywhere in the report background (the yellow part) to set the Properties window focus to Report, or select Report in the drop-down list at the top of the Properties window. You'll find the property there.

Comment: Still didn't work. still spaces where the information is being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the whitespaces you can use the builtin trim function and it will trim all the whitespaces.
For more details of SSRS function you can refer [here](http://bisqlserver2005.blogspot.com/2008/06/useful-built-in-functions-of-ssrs.html)

Comment: where do I implement the Trim Function?  I have a function written in to hide the Duplicate Fields already, and that is where the White Space Appears

Comment: I suggest you can try to trim the returned data as that will be lot easier option.Else if possible can you post what you are doing to hide duplicates that will be much easier for me to understand than throwing stones in air.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and what I found was that if I set the visibility of a rectangle to an expression and simply set the expression to =true, the rectangle shrank appropriately. I also had the report set to ConsumeContainerWhitespace although I'm not sure this is required in every case.