# SSRS hide white space from empty textbox outside of tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm new to both SSRS and development in general, and can't seem to find the answer to my problem. The report itself is simple-- a stored procedure collects responses and I display them using Lookup expressions in textboxes. Some fields are not required, so some of the textboxes are empty in my report. I would like to remove the white space left by the empty textbox.

In retrospect, I wish I had used a table to format the page, but since I have a very large number textboxes with expressions, I can't easily refactor my work. I found solutions for tablixes ([Trying to Get Rid of White Space in SSRS Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562043/trying-to-get-rid-of-white-space-in-ssrs-report)), but nothing for free-standing text boxes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on the textbox and navigate to 'Textbox Properties...' you can toggle the visibility of the textbox, and if it is hidden you wont see the white box. You could also enter expressions, like the one below for example will hide the textbox if there is no data in it.

```
=iif(isnothing(reportitems!Textbox1.Value),false,true)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize you could write a separate expression for the "hidden" property. Works great now